# Passing index between sibilings React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to pass index from one element to sibling element to show that in that second element. Couldn't find solution on internet for a second day in a row.

All i did to this point is showing data inside every div. I want to do it only on clicked one.

```
class Result extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
         showData: false
      }
    }

    showData = (el, index) => {
        this.setState({
            showData: !this.state.showData
        })
        console.log(el, index)
    }

    render() {
        const { dataFromSearchBar, inputValue } = this.props 
        const showData = this.state.showData
        let apiData = dataFromSearchBar.filter(el => {
            return el.launch_year === inputValue
        }).map((el, index) => {
            return (
                <div className={css(styles.result__data)}
                     key={index}>
                    <h2 onClick={() => this.showData(el, index)}>{el.mission_name}</h2>
                    {showData && 
                        <li key={index}>{el.launch_date_utc}</li>
                    }
                </div>
            )
        })
      return (
        <div className="result">
            {apiData}
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Here's app deployed on gh pages: https://kamilstaszewski.github.io/spacex-api-app/

Here you can find code for that app: https://github.com/KamilStaszewski/spacex-api-app/tree/master/src

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using redux ? or context API ?

Comment: im beginning to program, its just react, should i learn redux first? or maybe there's solution to that without installing / learning new libraries?

Comment: Yes you can everything without using redux

Comment: Note that `<li>` is not a valid html child of `<div>`

Comment: @charlietfl you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly , and you only want to display the clicked div data, then I suggest adding to the state another attribute like `displayIndex` :

```
  this.state = {
     displayIndex:-1
  }

showData = (el, index) => {
    this.setState(prevState) => ({
        displayIndex: index===prevState.displayIndex? -1 : index
    })
    console.log(el, index)
}
```

And then :

```
                {(index===this.state.displayIndex) && 
                    <li key={index}>{el.launch_date_utc}</li>
                }
```

Edit: if you want only one div to be displayed at any time then use this solution , if you want more than one then you should use arup approach

Comment: I don't think `showData` is not needed inside state anymore, because it was a try from the OP to achieve something that didn't work.. only `displayIndex` will do the work. Also `displayIndex` should not be `0`.

Comment: You're probably right :) but I'll leave it as it is because it will be the same as your answer . Also, as it is, it doesn't matter if displayIndex is 0 because showData is falsy

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep in the state currently clicked header index of the `Result` component. Like

```
this.state = {
  currentClickedResultIndex: []
}
```

Then change handler should be:

```
showData = index => e => {
  this.setState(({ currentClickedResultIndex }) => {
    if (currentClickedResultIndex.includes(index)) {
      return {
        currentClickedResultIndex: currentClickedResultIndex.filter(
          number => number !== index
        )
      };
    } else {
      return {
        currentClickedResultIndex: [...currentClickedResultIndex, index]
      };
    }
  });
};
```

And inside the rendered html from `Result` modify it as:

```
<h2 onClick={this.showData(index)}>{el.mission_name}</h2>;
{
  this.state.currentClickedResultIndex.includes(index) && (
    <li>{el.launch_date_utc}</li>
  );
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. The result is a little different from what i wanted. Maybe i havent written that before. I want to toggle the information. Now i can only show, cant go back to previous state. How to do that?

Comment: showData was still needed somehow haha , though it can be done only with currentClickedResultIndex

Comment: @sagi I will use your naming though currentClickedResultIndex .. :)

Comment: Nice solution btw, wasn't even thinking about displaying more than one divs data

Comment: I copied that and syntax is wrong. Is it working for you?

Comment: @ArupRakshit almost here, i got different error now: TypeError: currentClickedResultIndex.includes is not a function :D

Comment: forgot to change state to arr, but still it doesnt show data, no error now

Comment: oh youve made another change, ok now everything works, you rock bro thanks

Comment: I know, you are completely right, i just wanted to show any element for now. I'm from Poland.