# How to trigger just one dropdown among bunch of others created inside .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, stateful

Obviously, this is very noob question, but I'm stuck, so please help!

In my MenuWithDropdown Component I created bunch of dropdowns. The dropdown should be triggered with handleClick() function. What I'm trying to achieve is usually made with the help of this.state.isActive and ternary operator:

```
className={this.state.isActive ? "dropdown is-active" : "dropdown"}
```

However, I don't understand how could a trigger just one dropdown (for example number 3). Should I make state.isActive1, state.isActive2, state.isActive3 and somehow access them later in handleClick(key)? Or should I access the key property of dropdown, that it gets through map, like if (Dropdown.key === 3) setState(isActive:true)

```
class MenuWithDropdown extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false
  };

  render() {
    const { Menu } = this.props;

    const items = Menu.map((menuitem, key) => (
      <Fragment key={key}>
        <hr className="dropdown-divider" />

        <div key={key} className="dropdown is-left">
          <div className="dropdown-header">
            <NavLink to={menuitem.url}>
              <span>{this.context.t(menuitem.name)}</span>
            </NavLink>

            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="chevron-down" size="2x" />
          </div>

          <div className="dropdown-menu">
            <DropdownItem children={menuitem.children} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    ));
    return <Fragment>{items}</Fragment>;
  }

  handleClick = (e, key) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isActive: true
    });
  };
}
```

[image: Mobile Menu]

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52136665/passing-index-between-sibilings-react-js/) post. You will get the hint how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best and easiest ways of doing this would be to store the index(key) of the DropDownItem that has been clicked in your menuWithDropDown state from .map function and then give a prop to DropDownItem so it gets to check if by a condition of having the same index as menu state item index (which you previously stored), it should get open or not.
here is a version of your code to do the same as explained above: (hope it helps)

```
    class MenuWithDropdown extends React.Component {
            state = {
                activeItemKey: '',
            };

            render() {
                const { Menu } = this.props;

                const items = Menu.map((menuitem, key) => (
                    <Fragment key={key}>
                        <hr className="dropdown-divider" />

                        <div key={key} className="dropdown is-left">
                            <div className="dropdown-header">
                                <NavLink to={menuitem.url}>
                                    <span>{this.context.t(menuitem.name)}</span>
                                </NavLink>

                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon="chevron-down" size="2x" />
                            </div>

                            <div className="dropdown-menu">
                                <DropdownItem shouldOpen={this.state.activeItemKey === key} onClick={()=>{this.handleClick(key)}} children={menuitem.children} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Fragment>
                ));
                return <Fragment>{items}</Fragment>;
            }

            handleClick = (key) => {
                this.setState({
                    activeItemKey: key
                });
            };
    }
```

Comment: Mehmaz, thanks a lot for the idea, I changed it a bit and it works!

Answer (score 2):

The way I would design this menu is, basically, like this:
(check out this working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/toggling-menus)

Inside my App component, I have a `menus` state where I store the data for each menu.
On `componentDidMount` I generate the menus and pass the state to MenusContainer via props.

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      menus: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const menus = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Menu one',
        content: 'some content for menu 1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Menu two',
        content: 'some content for menu 2'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Menu three',
        content: 'some content for menu 3'
      }
    ];
    this.setState({menus})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MenusContainer menus={this.state.menus}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

MenusContainer will be responsible for rendering the menus, iterating its `menus` prop and setting the current menu.
For that it will have a `currentMenu` state and a setMenu method passing them as props to the `DropdownMenu` children rendered from `props.menus`.

```
export default class MenusContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentMenu: -1,
    }
  }
  setMenu = (id) => {
    if(id === this.state.currentMenu) {
      this.setState({currentMenu: -1})
    } else {
      this.setState({currentMenu: id})
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <div id='container'>
      {this.props.menus.map((menu, i) => {
        return <DropdownMenu 
                  key={i} 
                  data={menu} 
                  currentItem={this.state.currentMenu} 
                  setMenuCallback={this.setMenu}
                  />
      })}
    </div>
  }
}
```

The DropdownMenu will know (from props) which menu is currently requested and will fire a method to set itself as the current menu from its props.
Note that the menu will [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) its content according to `props.currentItem`.

```
export default class DropdownMenu extends React.Component {
  toggleSelf = () => {
    const {id} = this.props.data;
    this.props.setMenuCallback(id)
  }
  render() {
    return <div className='menu-item' onClick={this.toggleSelf}>
      <h1>{this.props.data.title}</h1>
      {
        this.props.currentItem === this.props.data.id ? 
          <div>{this.props.data.content}</div> : null
      }
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a solid approach, Amiry, thanks! Next time I would totally go for it and may be also add routes for <Router>, so Menu Component would be single source of truth for website structure

Answer (score 0):

OK, solution, thanks to Mehrnaz.sa, was really simple, to store an active key in the state, not the true-false boolean that open-close the dropdown.

Working code:

```
class MenuWithDropdown extends React.Component {

  state = {
    activeKey: 0
  }

  render() {

    const { Menu } = this.props

    const items = Menu.map((menuitem, key) =>

      <Fragment key={key}>
        <hr className="dropdown-divider" />

        <div key={key} 
         className={this.state.activeKey === key ? "dropdown is-left is-active" : "dropdown is-left"}>

          <div className="dropdown-header">
            <NavLink to={menuitem.url}>
              <span>{this.context.t(menuitem.name)}</span>
            </NavLink>

            //clicking on this icon trigger the dropdown 
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="chevron-down" size="2x" onClick={e => {this.handleClick(e, key)}}/>

          </div>
          <div className="dropdown-menu">
            // this is just a text, links to other parts of an app
            <DropdownItem children={menuitem.children} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {items}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }

  handleClick = (e, key) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({    
      activeKey: key
    })
  }
}
```